# Insert string in the right cells

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio, excel-2007

I have a problem that has not made me sleep at night for several days: I have an excel file containing a list of questions. For example, if a question contains the word "dog", the category it belongs to will be "pets".
I am developing a software in Visual Basic where, given a list of keywords, the program inserts the category next to the question

The program works on most PCs, but in some the list of categories appears next to the wrong question. Let me explain: the program finds the keyword in a question, but writes it in the wrong position on the excel sheet (next to another question)

Here is my code:

```
Dim xlsQuestions As Excel.Application
Dim index As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim nColsXls As Integer

'open excel file
xlsQuestions = CreateObject("EXCEL.APPLICATION")
xlsQuestions.Workbooks.Open(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/" + tbNomeFile.Text + ".xlsx")

For Each s As String In arrKeywords
nColsXls = 10
Dim arrValues(nColsXls) As String
index = 0
i = 2
j = 1

'inserted the category if the keyword is found in description
Do
  Do
    arrValues(index) = xlsQuestions.Cells(i, j).value
    index += 1
    j += 1
  Loop Until xlsQuestions.Cells(1, j).value = ""
  i += 1
  index = 0
  j = 1
  strQuestionText = arrValues(3)
  
  isPresent = strQuestionText.IndexOf(s)
  If isPresent <> -1 Then
  xlsQuestions.Cells(i - 1, 3).Value = "pet"
  End If
 Loop Until xlsQuestions.Cells(i, 4).value = ""
Next
```

This is the correct result that comes out on most PCs
[image: correct result]

This is the wrong result that comes out on some PCs

[image: the wrong result]

Comment: The for-loop loops trough animals right? It sounds like the first row in excel contains headers and that you loop trough all cells in row 2 and 3 and the first four cells in row 4 for some reason? Can you show an example of the excel file? Why do you only put the 3:d value into strQuestionText? What does cRow do? What is strCategoria?

Comment: The total columns of the excel sheet are 10. I corrected the code and added two screens representing the right and wrong output